# Remove join table records on destroy in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have Users, Roles, and Permissions.

When I delete a Role, I want to remove all Users and Permissions that are associated with that role in the join tables. **I don't want to delete the User or the Permission.**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => 'users_roles'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions, :join_table => 'roles_permissions'
end
```

Looking at the docs, you can use `:dependant` but that looks to destroy associated records as well. But I only want to destroy the join records.

I was thinking of doing:

```
after_destroy :remove_associated_users
after_destroy :remove_associated_permissions

def remove_associated_users
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    connection.execute("DELETE FROM users_roles WHERE role_id = " + self.id.to_s) 
end

def remove_associated_permissions
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    connection.execute("DELETE FROM roles_permissions WHERE role_id = " + self.id.to_s) 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `has_many :though` instead of a modelless HABTM relationship.

It has several advantages:

- the join table can be queried directly
- you can set callbacks on the join model
- you can add metadata to the join table if needed (such as timestamps, who granted the role etc.)

Start by creating a migration which renames the table from `users_roles` to `user_roles` as the former would cause rails to look for `Users::Role`. Do the same for the permissions join table.

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
  has_many :user_permissions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :permissions, through: :user_permissions
end

class UserPermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :permission
end

class Permission
  has_many :user_permissions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_permissions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use before_destroy callback

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => 'users_roles'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions, :join_table => 'roles_permissions'
  before_destroy { users.clear }
  before_destroy { permissions.clear }
end
```